# Visual Studio + Razor: "Surround with..." Snippets

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, code-snippets

I'm trying to use these awesome VS "Surround With" snippets with VS, but they dont't work as expected.
Say I have some code:

```
<p>Success!</p>
```

If I select this code and select the **ASP.NET MVC 4 / ifcs4** snippet, I would expect that my code becomes this:

```
@if (true) {
    <p>Success!</p>
}
```

But instead, it becomes this:

```
<% if (true) { %>
    <p>Success!</p>
<% } %>
```

These **<%** tags aren't even used in the Razor syntax, so why are they there? Isn't there any way I could put it to work in the expected manner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's just an oversight on Microsoft's part.

I found the snippets path by choosing Tools -> Code Snippets Manager, selected HTML as language and selected ifcs4. The path for the snippet is (for VS 2013):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Visual Studio 2013\Snippets\HTML\1033\ASP.NET MVC 4\ifcs.snippet

I updated the file with Razor-style if and it worked just fine even without reloading the project.

Comment: Nice. Whoa, it's a shame this feature is overseen by Microsoft. It is so nice and helpful, and also so easy to fix...